# How Height mode 4:3 works in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm working on wordpress as a new beginner and using the Visual Composer on development. It has a function called Post Grid when you build a page and it includes an option called item design lets user choosing grid element template.

User can choose Height mode when editing the template. there are 4:3, 3:4 and so on.

I wonder if anyone can tell me how this option work?

Thanks.

Comment: Your title is different from whats asked in the description. Its misleading. Can you edit the title.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is, Just give the padding-top a value of 75%

```
padding-top: 75%;
```